# How to automatically edit MySQL databases in Cpanel

Tags: mysql, flask, cpanel

I'm attempting to make a login system, and am hosting it on a web server using Namecheap. I decided to use the Cpanel MySQL Databases to save the login values (username, password, etc.), however, I haven't been able to add values to the MySQL databases. I can easily manually add to the databases, but how do I add using code (preferably python, but any language works as well).

**I don't have any previous attempts because I haven't found anything showing how to do this.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using php, which works just as well as it would in python.

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$servername = "localhost";
$server_username = "animfqrw_loginUsername";
$server_password = "loginPassword";
$dbname = "animfqrw_userLogin";
$userID = 1;

//Connects to the mysql database
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $server_username, $server_password, $dbname);

//Ends php code if php fails to connect to mysql database
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Error");
    break;
} 

//Finds the last User_ID
$sql = "SELECT User_ID FROM Users ORDER BY User_ID DESC LIMIT 1;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//Fetches the last User ID so that the User ID's are all in order
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $userID = $row["User_ID"] + 1;
}

//Add's the row to the mysql database
$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (User_ID, Username, Password)
VALUES ($userID, '$username', '$password')";
$conn->query($sql);

?>
```